# Any way to set parent background-color on the basis of child class using css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

is there any way to set parent background-color on the basis of child class using css?

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/bahodalila/edit?html,css,js,output
if child have `red` class parent should set `background-color` red.If child have `yellow` class parent should set `background-color` yellow.

```
<div class="par">
    
    <div class="red">
      helli
    </div>
  </div>



.par{
  background-color:red;
}

.par{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.par{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  
}


.red{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  color:red;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color:green
}
```

will I use `javascript` in this case ? is there any way to using `css` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2):

A pseudo element can simulate this:

```css
.par {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position:relative; /* here and not on child to make it relative to parent*/
  z-index:0;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: green;
}
.red::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="par">

  <div class="red">
    helli
  </div>
</div>


<div class="par">

  <div class="red" style="background:blue;">
    helli
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using **:has() CSS pseudo-class**

```
.par:has(.red){
  background-color:red;
}

.par:has(.yellow){
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

**note that its not supported in Firefox [can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I looked at the linked canIuse entry, and noticed that the users can enable this functionality via `about:config`, and then setting `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` to **`true`**. The info is present in the tooltips for 103-119 and 120 versions.

Answer (score 0):

CSS and DIV do not use the parent-child methodology. You will need to create each variable in CSS and set each DIV to the CSS variable you want. I did an example using your code to show.

```css
.par{
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.par-yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.red{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  color:red;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color:green
}
```

```html
<div class="par">
  <div class="par-yellow">    
    <div class="red">
      helli
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no parent [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) on css. A workaround is only with JS posible. You could do something like:

```
var redElements = document.querySelectorAll(".red");
for(var i = 0; i < redElements.length; i++){
  redElements[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```